# What do the shaded vertical lines in the animation of Gravity assists of space probes, mean?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, probe, physics, gravity-assist

Example Animations from Wikipedia —

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist#/media/File:Animation_of_Voyager_1_trajectory.gif

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Animation_of_Pioneer_11_trajectory.gif

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Animation_of_Pioneer_11_trajectory_around_Jupiter.gif

An example of the lines being asked about is indicated by the red arrow.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about these lines (red arrow)? https://imgur.com/ef0UY5z  Suggest adding this picture to your question (I can do it if your rep does not allow). Anyway, it looks like it's the distance from the ecliptic plane.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Yes, those lines. I couldn't add the pic.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it, no problem.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - But the orbital planes of all planets are not much different from the ecliptic plane. Are you sure it's the distance from the ecliptic? As it doesn't make sense of continuously increasing distance.

Comment: I'm not answering, just commenting. Someone will come along and give a good answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - cool. Thanks.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I just noticed you already answered in a comment, I've edited my answer to reference it.

Comment: This was a great question! fyi I've just asked [Why did Pioneer 11 use a gravitational assist to swing above the ecliptic plane... twice?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44129/12102)

Comment: @uhoh Thanks, I was just guessing. You wrote an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@OrganicMarble nailed it: [...it looks like it's the distance from the ecliptic plane.](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44117/what-do-the-shaded-vertical-lines-in-the-animation-of-gravity-assists-of-space-p/44125#comment142596_44117)

Yep, it's height above/below the ecliptic, a way to represent 3D in a 2D plot.

At first I thought they might be thrust vectors [like these](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38906/12102) but no, these are ballistic arcs. Instead I am 99.44% certain that these lines are use to indicate height above/below the plane of the ecliptic.

Below is the GIF for Pioneer 11 from Earth to a Jupiter flyby to Saturn. I've downloaded the data from [JPL's Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) and plotted it. In the 2D plot in the plane of the ecliptic I've added lines every 100 days whose lengths in the $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ direction are equal to the position in $\mathbf{z}$. It seems to match well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

final frame of [this GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Animation_of_Pioneer_11_trajectory.gif)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

class Body(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def rotate_it(vec, theta):
    cth, sth = [f(theta) for f in (np.cos, np.sin)]
    x, y, z = vec
    xr = cth*x - sth*y
    yr = cth*y + sth*x
    return np.vstack((xr, yr, z))

def makecubelimits(axis, centers=None, hw=None):
    # xlims, ylims, zlims = ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(), ax.get_zlim()
    lims = ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(), ax.get_zlim()
    # llims, ulims = zip(*lims)
    if centers == None:
        centers = [0.5*sum(pair) for pair in lims] 

    if hw == None:
        widths  = [pair[1] - pair[0] for pair in lims]
        hw      = 0.5*max(widths)
        ax.set_xlim(centers[0]-hw, centers[0]+hw)
        ax.set_ylim(centers[1]-hw, centers[1]+hw)
        ax.set_zlim(centers[2]-hw, centers[2]+hw)
        print ('hw was None so set to: ', hw)
    else:
        try:
            hwx, hwy, hwz = hw
            print('ok hw requested: ', hwx, hwy, hwz)

            ax.set_xlim(centers[0]-hwx, centers[0]+hwx)
            ax.set_ylim(centers[1]-hwy, centers[1]+hwy)
            ax.set_zlim(centers[2]-hwz, centers[2]+hwz)
        except:
            print ('nope hw requested: ', hw)
            ax.set_xlim(centers[0]-hw, centers[0]+hw)
            ax.set_ylim(centers[1]-hw, centers[1]+hw)
            ax.set_zlim(centers[2]-hw, centers[2]+hw)

    return centers, hw

names  = ['Sun', 'Earth', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Pioneer_11']

halfpi, pi, twopi = [f*np.pi for f in [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]]
degs, rads        = 180./pi, pi/180.
AU                = 149597870.700  # kilometers

bodies = []
for name in names: # horizons_results Pioneer_11.txt
    fname = 'horizons_results ' + name + '.txt'
    with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
        lines = infile.read().splitlines()

    iSOE = [i for i, line in enumerate(lines) if "$$SOE" in line][0]
    iEOE = [i for i, line in enumerate(lines) if "$$EOE" in line][0]

    print(iSOE, iEOE, lines[iSOE], lines[iEOE])
    lines = [line.split(',') for line in lines[iSOE+1:iEOE]]
    JD  = np.array([float(line[0]) for line in lines])
    pos = np.array([[float(item) for item in line[2:5]] for line in lines])
    vel = np.array([[float(item) for item in line[5:8]] for line in lines])
    body = Body(name)
    body.lines = lines
    body.JD = JD
    body.pos = pos.T.copy()
    body.vel = vel.T.copy()
    bodies.append(body)

theta = +np.pi/4.

for body in bodies:
    body.pos_r = rotate_it(body.pos, -theta)
    body.vel_r = rotate_it(body.vel, -theta)

Sun, Earth, Jupiter, Saturn, Pioneer_11 = bodies

if True:    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 8])  # [12, 10]
    ax  = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

    for body in bodies:
        x, y, z = body.pos
        ax.plot(x, y, z)

    c, h = makecubelimits(ax, centers=(0, 0, 0), hw=None)
    print(c, h)
    plt.show()

if True:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 8])  # [12, 10]
    ax  = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

    for body in bodies:
        x, y, z = body.pos_r
        ax.plot(x, y)
        for x, y, z in Pioneer_11.pos_r.T[::100]:
            plt.plot([x, x], [y, y-z], '-k')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I should have drawn the lines in the 3D plot then viewed at an angle, rather than in a 2D plot, With that perspective my plot would match exactly. Right now Saturn looks a little funky relative to Pioneer 11 at the upper left because of the projection on to the ecliptic and the lack of perspective.

Comment: I've just asked [Why did Pioneer 11 use a gravitational assist to swing above the ecliptic plane... twice?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44129/12102)